# Error running '__rvm_make -j8' in macos Monterey

Tags: ruby, macos, openssl, rvm

I'm trying to install ruby 2.7.0 using RVM on MacOS(12.4: apple M2), but i'm getting below error and not able to install required ruby version. I have tried all the solutions available on internet related to openssl but nothing works for me and tried with rbenv also but no luck. Please help me, thank you in advance.

Current version: OpenSSL 1.1.1s  1 Nov 2022

[image]

```
+__rvm_make:0> make -j8
        BASERUBY = /usr/bin/ruby --disable=gems
        CC = gcc
        LD = ld
        LDSHARED = gcc -dynamiclib
        CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb3 -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration -std=gnu99  -fno-common -pipe
        XCFLAGS = -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT -DCANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN -I. -I.ext/include/-darwin21 -I./include -I. -I./enc/unicode/12.1.0
        CPPFLAGS = -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT
        DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -install_name /Users/rashmib/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/libruby.2.7.dylib -compatibility_version 2.7 -current_version 2.7.0  -fstack-protector-strong -framework Security -framework Foundation  -fstack-protector-strong -framework Security -framework Foundation
        SOLIBS = -lpthread -ldl -lobjc
        LANG =
        LC_ALL =
        LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
        MFLAGS = - --jobserver-fds=4,5 -j
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
compiling ./main.c
compiling dmydln.c
compiling miniinit.c
compiling dmyext.c
translating probes probes.d
compiling bignum.c
compiling class.c
compiling ast.c
. ./vm_opts.h
compiling compar.c
compiling compile.c
compiling complex.c
compiling cont.c
bignum.c:6127:33: warning: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
        return rb_num_coerce_bin(x, y, rb_intern("remainder"));
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/ruby/ruby.h:1847:23: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                      ^
bignum.c:6127:33: note: '{' token is here
        return rb_num_coerce_bin(x, y, rb_intern("remainder"));
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/ruby/ruby.h:1847:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/ruby/ruby.h:1832:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    {                                                   \
    ^
bignum.c:6127:33: warning: '}' and ')' tokens terminating statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
return rb_num_coerce_bin(x, y, rb_intern("remainder"));
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/ruby/ruby.h:1847:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/ruby/ruby.h:1837:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    }
    ^
bignum.c:6127:33: note: ')' token is here
        return rb_num_coerce_bin(x, y, rb_intern("remainder"));
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/ruby/ruby.h:1847:56: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                                                       ^
class.c:541:13: warning: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
```

[image: rbenv error log]

Comment: You forgot to add the error itself (the tail of the `...ruby-2.7.1/make.log` file that is mentioned above)...

Comment: Updated the error log.

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting from rbenv? Is it the same error? I am running 2.7.0 on my m1 Monterey and it works fine for me. I have downloaded it via rbenv.

Comment: I have added error logs for rbenv also.

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext as [they are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). Please copy and paste plaintext into your question.

Answer (score 1):

After trying lot of suggestions, following these steps worked for me

1. MAC ports installation
   https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration
2. Run
   `rvm install 2.7.0 --with-out-ext=fiddle`

Answer (score 0):

When you will get error related to __rvm_make -j4 + mac monterey run this below code with your openssl path
This worked for me.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
 export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
 export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
 export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"

 rvm autolibs disable

 export RUBY_CFLAGS=-DUSE_FFI_CLOSURE_ALLOC
 export optflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"

 rvm install 2.7.0 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).